# kableExtra define width/wrap does not work when content is a long string without space?

Tags: r, kableextra

I would like to wrap a column with a long string however this only seem to work if the content are separated by space. For example:

```
iris$Species = as.character(iris$Species  )
iris[1, ]$Species = 'long string, fff,ffdfdfd,ffdfdfd,dfdfdfdfd,ffdfssdfdafdfa,fdfdafdfds,daffdfafdfds,affdaffdsa,fdfasfsafa,adfdafsaf,aaaaaaaaaaalloooonnnng'

kbl( iris , format = "html" , row.names = F, caption = "test",
) %>% 
  kable_paper(full_width= FALSE, position = "center")  %>%
  column_spec(5, width = "20px", background = "grey")
```

so for because row 1, col 5 is one long string the field would just extend outwards and not wrap.

Is there a way around this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the commas with breaks

```
iris$Species = as.character(iris$Species  )
iris[1, ]$Species = 'long string, fff,ffdfdfd,ffdfdfd,dfdfdfdfd,ffdfssdfdafdfa,fdfdafdfds,daffdfafdfds,affdaffdsa,fdfasfsafa,adfdafsaf,aaaaaaaaaaalloooonnnng'

irisNew <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = str_replace_all(Species, ',', '<br>'))

kbl( irisNew , format = "html" , row.names = F, caption = "test", escape = F
) %>% 
  kable_paper(full_width= FALSE, position = "center")  %>%
  column_spec(5, width = "20px", background = "grey")
```

[image: sample]

Or use the Zero Width Space unicode character

```
irisNew <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = str_replace_all(Species, ',', '&#8203;'))

kbl( irisNew , format = "html" , row.names = F, caption = "test", escape = F
) %>% 
  kable_paper(full_width= FALSE, position = "center")  %>%
  column_spec(5, width = "20px", background = "grey")
```

[image: sample2]

Comment: the zero width space is a great idea; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a space every N number of characters using `gsub()`, which will work in HTML outputs. If you are printing to Latex, introduce a new line `\n` instead. The following introduces a space every 10 characters.

```
iris$Species = as.character(iris$Species)

long <- 'long string, fff,ffdfdfd,ffdfdfd,dfdfdfdfd,ffdfssdfdafdfa,fdfdafdfds,daffdfafdfds,affdaffdsa,fdfasfsafa,adfdafsaf,aaaaaaaaaaalloooonnnng'

iris[1, ]$Species = gsub('(?=(?:.{10})+$)', " ", long, perl = TRUE)

kbl( iris , format = "html" , row.names = F, caption = "test",
) %>% 
  kable_paper(full_width= FALSE, position = "center")  %>%
  column_spec(5, width = "20px", background = "grey")
```